# How to send email with Amazon SES using a pure HTTP request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to send email using the Amazon SES without using aws-sdk. I need to send it using just a pure HTTP request. In other words, how can I send email with Amazon SES using cURL?

Comment: SES is email service. It doesn't have HTTP interface; only SMTP.

Comment: What is this then? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html

Comment: well - this is API reference. However, I stand corrected - there are HTTPS endpoints as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html#ses_region I also see that HTTPS is the most advanced way, since you need to set up all headers yourself. But I can't find any documentation on HTTPS in SES either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SES has email service and it is possible to quite easily check what is being sent with some external tool to sniff the requests that are being sent from your computer. On the other hand, keep in mind that if you want to do it purely using cURL, you have to also handle authentication and signing your requests before, which will create a lot of additional work.

Here you have example request syntax:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/API_SendEmail.html

Link for the signature (I believe that was the things that oyu were looking for) etc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html

Here you have the link for the endpoints:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html